Calculating Area of 2D Shape in 3D space
With ArcGIS Pro, I want to calculate the area of a roof. I have LoD2 building data and have only exported the roofs. These roofs have a 2D shape but are situated in a 3D space. When I calculate the area of the geometry, it is equal to the 2D area. I know this because I have the roofs as 2D footprints and have performed an area calculation there as well. However, the roofs in the 3D space should have a larger area due to their slope.
So far, I have not found a good method to calculate the area of the 3D roof.
 
My current approach is to use a raster-based surface model to calculate the slope and determine the area for each raster cell, then sum these areas for each roof to approximate the total area.
Do you have any other or better approach ideas?

Do you have the 3D analyst extension ? The tools to calculate 3D surface are in the 3D analyst toolbox

Yes I do. Which tool do you mean? Can you provide a link to ESRIs doc?

Unfortunately not. The 'Add Surface Information Tool' does not process MultiPatch data and also does not calculate the area of the features. Unless I am missing something.

https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/spatial-analysis/3d-visual/3d-measurement/ I am looking for a tool like this. But for ArcGIS Pro to automate the process.

To get the area I used the tool: "add Z-information".
The features have a Z value that isn't considered in the geometry calculation. Only through the tool "add Z-information" can the Z information be added, and a 3D area from a 2D polygon that’s in space will be displayed in the attribute table.
